# Is list=False parameter planned for future zip() versions (new in Python 3.10 strict=False)?

Tags: python-3.x

Since Python version 3.10 the builtin function `zip()` allows usage of the parameter `strict` with the default value of `False` providing the option of setting `strict=True` which rises a `TypeError` in case the iterables don't have equal lengths (helps with debugging).

**Is there also an option `list=False` in the pipeline which if set to `list=True` returns a list of lists instead of a list of tuples? If not: is there a good reason why not?**

---

From the comments:

---

> Sounds like you want `map(list, zip(...))` - *khelwood*

This will go twice over the full length of the zipped items and an own zip() written in Python will slow things down. Another option is `[list(e) for e in zip(...)]` with the same disadvantage. What I want is a list=True option for zip and wonder why isn't it there? Probably there is a good reason for that I am not aware of. Packing in tupels first and repacking it afterwards into lists makes not much sense. Tuples are more restricted than lists cutting down the number of possible direct operations on the result. In my eyes more Pythonic were to return a list of lists which gives more flexibility - the reason why I wonder and ask the question.

> Generally you use zip to iterate over pairs like for x, y in zip(...)

Yes, but another use of zip() is for transposing a 2D list of lists array (provided e.g. in `numpy` with `.T`) and want as result a list of lists and not a list of tuples in order to be able to operate on the array elements.

Comment: Sounds like you want `map(list, zip(...))`

Comment: This goes twice over the full length of the zipped items and an own zip() written in Python will slow things down. Another option is `[list(e) for e in zip(...)]` with the same disadvantage. What I want is a `list=True` option for zip and wonder why isn't it there??? Packing it in tupels first and repacking it afterwards into lists makes not much sense. Tuples are more restricted than lists cutting down the number of possible direct operations on the result.

Comment: I am using zip() for transposing 2D list of lists arrays and want as result a list of lists and not a list of tuples.

Comment: Generally you use `zip` to iterate over pairs like `for x, y in zip(...):`. In that case there is no reason to return lists instead of tuples, and it would be less performant since lists generally take more space than tuples, in order to have room to grow.

Comment: @Claudio: To be clear, `[list(e) for e in zip(...)]` has two disadvantages that `map(list, zip(...))` lacks: 1) It's a listcomp (eager) where `map` is lazy (`(list(e) for e in zip(...))` avoids that cost, but has higher CPU overhead if you run it to exhaustion); with `map`, you only have one `list` output at a time, just like `zip` only produces one `tuple` at a time, and 2) The listcomp (and genexpr replacement) both break the `zip` optimization to reuse `tuple`s (because `e` still exists when the next `e` is requested), so you build a new `tuple` and `list` per loop, not just a new `list`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such plan. The benefit is trivial, and would slow down *all* uses of `zip` a little bit to enable a use case that isn't needed 99+% of the time.

In the (likely less than) 1% of the cases where it's needed, it can be achieved trivially with `map(list, zip(...))`, which has surprisingly low overhead, as:

1. `map` is still lazy, so you're not producing any large intermediate data structures, and it's also implemented in C, so you don't pop in and out of the bytecode interpreter layer as you go (each new item involves a single call down into the C layer which does all the work to produce the next item "atomically"),
2. Conversion from known sized `tuple` to `list` is incredibly cheap (creating or extending a `list` from an existing `list` or `tuple` is special-cased to be as performant as possible since it's such a common case), and
3. On the CPython reference interpreter, `zip` itself has an optimization that recognizes when the `tuple` it produces is not referenced elsewhere when the next one is requested and *reuses* that `tuple` for the next output (so in fact, you only produce one truly new `tuple`, and otherwise only generate new `list`s; the optimization for `tuple`s would likely be useless for `list`s since if you wanted a `list`, you probably intended to modify it and therefore it couldn't be reused reliably even if you dropped all references to it before the next loop). The overhead of having it produce a `tuple` first becomes trivial enough due to this optimization (which also benefits cases like `for x, y in zip(it1, it2):`) that the incremental benefit of directly producing a `list` is not enough to justify the change.

The optimization from item #3 in particular is a strict reason *not* to do this; to preserve the optimization for `tuple`s, the code for `zip`'s `tp_next` (the C equivalent of the `__next__` that iterators have to produce the next value) would get more complicated, and expanding a cheap function called many times even a little can have big impacts on performance (if nothing else, it introduces at least one additional test-and-branch based on the `zip` "mode", and adds specialized code needed to work efficiently with a `list` (on top of the existing code for `tuple`s) at the C layer. This might not seem like much; it might only add a nanosecond to the overhead per item in `tuple` mode, but given how often the method is called, and how this would slow the common (`tuple`) case to support the uncommon case (`list`), it's hard to justify.

For the record, the true cost of `map(list, ...)` wrapping seems to be multiplying overhead by approximately 3x for the simple case of `zip`ing two sequences (timings from CPython 3.10.5 on Linux x86-64, using IPython 8.4.0 `%%timeit` magic to simplify microbenchmarks):

```
>>> %%timeit a = tuple(range(1000)); b = tuple(range(1000, 2000))
... for tup in zip(a, b):
...     pass
15.7 μs ± 216 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

>>> %%timeit a = tuple(range(1000)); b = tuple(range(1000, 2000))
... for lst in map(list, zip(a, b)):
...     pass
47 μs ± 1.09 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

All things considered, that's pretty good, ~30 ns of overhead per item to get `list`s instead of `tuple`. For comparison, the cost of doing just *one* meaningful thing with said `list`, say, calling `lst.append(1)` as the body of the loop, adds ~45 ns of cost, so basically anything you'd *do* with said `list` would cost more than the incremental expense of getting `list`s in the first place. It's just not that big a deal for something that comes up so rarely. If supporting `list=True` added just 1 ns of overhead to the `tuple` case, you'd need to prove that the `list=True` case would occur at least one out of every 30 cases (more like one out of ten or so cases in practice, since `zip` would run even slower for the `list` case since `list`s require two allocations, not one, and aren't quite as heavily optimized for repeated allocation of small fixed size `list`s as `tuple`s are), and I guarantee you the ratio is nowhere close to that in real world code.

Comment: Yes, it sounds reasonable especially considering the tuple optimization. Thanks for providing an insight into the internals of CPython.

Comment: @Claudio: You're welcome. For comparison, `strict=True` was okay (despite being one of a few things they explicitly laid out as "Won't dos" when they were planning for Python 3) because it's roughly fixed overhead (it adds a little parsing overhead to parse the arguments when creating the `zip` object and for the `strict=False` case just adds a single boolean check on when the first iterator is exhausted), not per-item overhead, so the cost doesn't scale with input size.